# where do you get some libraries for SuSe OS

Tags: suse

I need to install some open source libraries like R base and this depends on some other library called libgtran.so and this depends on some other libraries like libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit) is needed by libgfortran47-4.7.1_20120723-1.1.1.x86_64
        libquadmath.so.0()(64bit) is needed by libgfortran47-4.7.1_20120723-1.1.1.x86_64
        libquadmath.so.0(QUADMATH_1.0)(64bit) is needed by libgfortran47-4.7.1_20120723-1.1.1.x86_64
        libquadmath0 >= 4.7.1_20120723-1.1.1 is needed by libgfortran47-4.7.1_20120723-1.1.1.x86_64

etc.

Is there any repository out there where we can point to and install libraries with dependencies in SuSe OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Open Build Service (https://build.opensuse.org) to get this Package for SUSE Linux Enterprise or for openSUSE.